# Is it possible to use ubuntu with fedora kernel?

Tags: kernel

Ubuntu/mainline kernel have acpi problems with my notebook's firmware but fedora hasn't. I think it is patched or something, however I hate fedora and I would like to use Ubuntu with this kernel. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so you may wish to wait for others. Yes you could use a fedora kernel, but some functions Ubuntu relies on (eg. snaps.snapcraft) will not work unless you use a fedora kernel with those functions enabled. You didn't specify any versions, but you risk some functions not working (due differences) same as you get with any non-Ubuntu kernel.  How this will affect you depends on what you use it for (eg. tuxedo laptops sold ubuntu but didn't use Ubuntu kernel which resulted in mixed reviews as some reviewers found some functions didn't work b/c of non-Ubuntu kernels installed)